# WFA Progress bar Background color or texture (not foreground)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been looking for this solution for a quite long time, here, or other guidance sites.. But many people want to just chhange the foreground color of progressbar (the part, which is rising with progress)

I think, my small image can say everything:

http://screenshot.cz/WT5KO/progbar.png

Now, I am using this code to paint custom bar, which you can see above. Is it possible compose the background-edit code into my constructor code?

```
 public class NewProgressBar : ProgressBar
{
    public NewProgressBar()
    {
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);

    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs pevent)
    {
        // None... Helps control the flicker.
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        const int inset = 0; // A single inset value to control teh sizing of the inner rect.

        using (Image offscreenImage = new Bitmap(this.Width, this.Height))
        {
            using (Graphics offscreen = Graphics.FromImage(offscreenImage))
            {


                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width, this.Height);


                if (ProgressBarRenderer.IsSupported)
                    ProgressBarRenderer.DrawHorizontalBar(offscreen, rect);

                rect.Inflate(new Size(-inset, -inset)); // Deflate inner rect.
                rect.Width = (int)(rect.Width * ((double)this.Value / this.Maximum));
                if (rect.Width == 0) rect.Width = 1; // Can't draw rec with width of 0.
                TextureBrush mybrush = new TextureBrush(Properties.Resources.loading);
                LinearGradientBrush brush = new LinearGradientBrush(rect, Color.DarkGoldenrod, Color.Gold, LinearGradientMode.Vertical);
                offscreen.FillRectangle(mybrush, inset, inset, rect.Width, rect.Height);

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(offscreenImage, 0, 0);
                offscreenImage.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I use WFA template under .NET 4.5

thanks in advance

Comment: Is it a WinForms control?

Comment: I think it would be wise to add the exact name of the GUI toolkit you're using, to attract more experts. Generally, well-descripting tags make questions better.

Comment: If you want to change the background, why not `OnPaintBackground`?

Comment: hi, sorry for missing info (added now)

yes, it is WFA template
OnpaintBackground - if I understand it right, it is "what will happens, if the background will be painted"

As you can see, the progressbar is a collection of parts, like rectangles (see in snippet). I need to find a piece of code, that will rewrite the definition of what will be actually painted. I have been looking for originall ProgressBar class to edit it, but I haven't find anything useful :(

Answer (score 1):

You are using visual progress bar style on your custom progress bar because you declare your control as progress bar at your class.

```
public class NewProgressBar : ProgressBar
```

if you want to make your own please switch your custom control class declaration into Control

```
public class NewProgressBar : Control
```

then you will able to use BackColor
but you need to code 'value, minimum/maximum value,' by your own to make that progress bar works